# Evaluate formula in Excel Selenium JAVA at runtime

Tags: java, selenium, excel-formula, automated-tests, apache-poi

I am trying to write a set of values to excel columns Say A,B where  column C has formula `=VLOOKUP(A2,workbook!$A$1:$J$500,2,FALSE)` to be evaluated and its values should be saved in Column C itself once columns A and B are written/filled up after file write.My problem after the values are written in A &B formula in C is not evaluated automatically.
i tried this code below.can someone suggest a solution? Thanks in advance.,

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Constants.DATALOADER_RESULTS_PATH+"Excelfile1.xlsx"));
worbook.write(out);
out.close();
FormulaEvaluator evaluator =worbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
evaluator.evaluateAll();
```

Comment: are you evaluating the cell using `CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);`?

Comment: No I just tried to evaluate the complete workbook., using evaluator.evaluateAll();

Comment: Formula evaluation must be done before writing out the workbook.